# retrieve a specific data from the selected index in a TreeModel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qstandarditemmodel

I used a custom model to populate the`TreeView` and tried using

> ```
>         for ix in self.dataView.selectedIndexes():
>             text = ix.data()  # or ix.data()
>             print(text)
> ```
>
> but this prints all the data in that column(index)...here is a picture of the model i used `model = QStandardItemModel(0, 3, parent)`, [image: model used]

My problem is i don't need all the data, i need the data of the 3rd row (specific data) i.e the filepath

this is the output, using the later code

```
We & Love.txt
11.630% 
C:\Users\Black Laptop\Desktop\Work\We & Love.txt
```

i just need the 3rd data, not all, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QModelIndex are associated to each item, in your case you have the one of the complete row, so the solution is to filter by the column:

```py
for ix in self.dataView.selectedIndexes():
    # the indexes of the column start at 0 so the 3rd column has index 2
    if ix.column() == 2:
        text = ix.data()
        print(text)
```

Comment: pls is there any resource you can recommend for me to get better...?

Comment: @X-Black... Read the docs of Qt, although it shows examples of C++ it is easily understandable and translatable to python, but the most important thing is the explanation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html